# Hibernate envers ignores types from hibernate-types-52 library

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers, hibernate-types

I'm having an entity which is audited using hibernate envers. Using "jsonb" type from hibernate-types-52 library for one of the fields. Example:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "entity")
class Entity() {

@Type(type = "jsonb")
@Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
var field1: Map<String, Any> = emptyMap()

}
```

And here's the generated SQL:

```
 create table entity (
    field1 jsonb
 )

create table entity_aud (
    field1 uuid     
 )
```

As you can see, jsonb type is not being used for field1 in _aud table. Experiencing same behavior when using psql_enum type. This of course makes an exception, when trying to persist an entity. How can I make envers recognize such a types and make it generate schema accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, this is because Hibernate maps the JDBC `Types.OTHER` to `PostgresUUIDType`.

As I explained in [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type/), you can create a custom `Dialect` that extends the `PostgreSQLDialect`:

```
public class PostgreSQL10JsonDialect
        extends PostgreSQL10Dialect {
 
    public PostgreSQL10JsonDialect() {
        super();
        this.registerHibernateType(
            Types.OTHER, JsonNodeBinaryType.class.getName()
        );
    }
}
```

And if we provide the custom `PostgreSQL10JsonDialect` via the `hibernate.dialect` configuration property:

```
<property 
    name="hibernate.dialect"
    value="com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.type.json.PostgreSQL10JsonDialect"
/>
```